# Autoplay and Observer in SwiperSlider (Vue 3)

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, swiper.js

I have a swiper slider on vue 3 in the middle of the page

```
<swiper
        :modules="modules"
        :slides-per-view="1.5"
        :space-between="15"
        @activeIndexChange="onSlideChange"
    >
```

How do I start autoplay when the user scrolls to the right place? As far as I can tell, Swiper doesn't have any suitable events.

I tried to use this code:

```
setup() {
    const onSwiper = (swiper) => {
      if (!window.IntersectionObserver) {
        let observer = new IntersectionObserver(
            (entries, observer) => {
              entries.forEach((entry) => {
                if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                  console.log(entry);
                  swiper.autoplay.start()
                  // You can remove the observer if you do not need it
                  observer.unobserve(entry.target);
                }
              });
            },
            { rootMargin: "0px 0px -200px 0px" }
        );

        // Add the observer to you swiper
        observer.observe(document.querySelector(".home-slider"));
      }
    };
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `IntersectionObserver` registration, remove the `if` around it:

```js
if (!window.IntersectionObserver) {
```

This means "if `IntersectionObserver` is unavailable" which will evaluate to false in most modern browsers, since most modern browsers support `IntersectionObserver`. So having this `if` means that the code inside of this conditional never runs.

Ensure you have a reference to the `swiper` object, by using the `swiper` event:

```js
<script>
export default {
  …
  methods: {
    onSwiper(swiper) {
      …
    },
  },
}
</script>

<swiper
  …
  @swiper="onSwiper"
>
```

Move your `IntersectionObserver` code inside the `onSwiper` method:

```js
onSwiper(swiper) {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
    ([entry]) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        swiper.autoplay.start();
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    },
    { threshold: 0 }
  );
  observer.observe(swiper.el);
},
```

Use `threshold: 0` to be notified of when even 1 pixel of the swiper becomes visible – adjust as you'd like.

Pass `swiper.el` to `.observe()`. This will mean that that we are always observing the swiper in this component. Your code had `document.querySelector(".home-slider")` but your swiper code did not have `class="home-slider"` so your `.observe()` call would not observe the swiper element I presume you'd intend.

Ensure the `Autoplay` module is passed to `<swiper>`:

```js
<script>
import { Autoplay } from 'swiper/modules';
…
export default {
  …
  setup() {
    return {
      …
      modules: [Autoplay],
    };
  },
  …
}
</script>
```

Live example in [this Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-as6inv?file=src%2FApp.vue).